# iOS: Data Storage and Download Support Services

Tags: ios, download, storage

I have an iOS application that allows the users to download content and then use it. During development i used [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) for data storage and download purposes. Now i'm looking for a deployment solution. A service that can handle many concurrents downloads with decent download speed, provides sufficient storage space, is secure, and not very expensive. Optionally, if it provides Download Tracking/Monitoring features, then that'll be a plus.

[Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) looks like a viable option. What other choices do i have?

Comment: hy Dropbox isn't sufficient? They're free, with good download speeds and have an excellent iOS API client.

Comment: For a single user, yes. But what about 2000 or 20,000 users downloading the same file? There's no documentation that Dropbox can handle such load. Or is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we ended up using Rackspace which we think is more appropriate for our situation. And regarding the bandwidth limitation of Dropbox, here's what their representative said:

> We automatically ban public links when they are responsible for an
>   uncommonly large amount of traffic. These include all of the sharing
>   links, not just the Public folder links.
>
> The limit is 10GB/day for free accounts. Paid accounts have a much
>   higher limit of 250GB/day. While we want you to be able to share your
>   files with your friends we can't be a content delivery network for the
>   entire Internet.
>
> Links are banned temporarily (3 days for the first time) and accounts
>   will eventually restore their public links.

So, dropbox was not an option.